# How to use "Send and receive messages" in AWS Console to send large messages to AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

In Java, there is a library that allows sending large messages to SQS queue via using S3. For that I can use `amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib` library and then, using the same library, I am able to receive such message from the queue making it transparent whether S3 was used or not

By reverse engineering the code that does so ([here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/AmazonSQSExtendedClient.java#L340C1-L340C61)) it seems when a large file is sent via the library, the library first uploads the real payload to S3 and then sends a message to the queue with an specific attribute and a pointer payload to the S3 entry. For receiving, the library checks whether the attribute is there and if it is, it downloads the "real" payload from S3

I have an application that uses `amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib` for receiving messages from SQS and I want to send large messages to this queue via the AWS Console (for testing purposes), so I uploaded a file to S3 a then tried to send the  below message that contains the pointer payload and contains the attribute "ExtendedPayloadSize", but was unsuccessful: the `amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib` doesn't seem to download the "real" payload but rather use the pointer payload sent

Anyone had tried to do this before and succeeded?

[image]

Comment: "I've tried to send the below message that contains the pointer payload and contains the attribute "ExtendedPayloadSize", but was unsuccessful?" So you uploaded the message contents to S3 first, and then posted this message to the queue? What specifically was unsuccessful? Did you get an error message of some kind? Please edit your question to provide exact details of what error or unexpected behavior you encountered.

Comment: I updated the question to includes more deatils and to be more exact